# How to safely carry a fixed-blade knife?

Tags: knives

I worry about carrying a fixed-blade knife on my hip, because if I fall or wrestle my kids or whatever, I worry I could get stabbed. I've had pointy blades push through a cheap sheath before.

I stick to folding knives for this reason, but I like the idea of a knife I can quickly get out with just one hand.

Comment: I always feel uneasy at the idea of carrying around a fixed blade. I think it may get you in trouble with the law if they stop you with one around. I think if you have a well locked foldable is much better legally.

Comment: If you want to consider a folding knife that can be opened with one hand, I have this assisted open knife, and I can definitely get it out and open with one hand (with practice, as the lock is solid and I have small hands):  http://www.buckknives.com/index.cfm?event=product.detail&productID=3644.

Comment: I do not understand. **Most** pocket knifes are designed to be opened with one hand.

Comment: @Vorac: A lot of knives out there look like this, and require 2 hands. http://i.imgur.com/Re1RnfQ.jpg

Comment: Why would you want such a blade. You can't open it with one hand.

Comment: If we are talking legally, at least for Canada most all completely illegal knives are folders. knife legislation is based on gang stereotypes and and that means switchblades, butterfly, and other structurally similar knives (which can technically include things all the way up to Swiss army).

Comment: @Vorac In some countries you cannot carry a knife designed to be opened with one hand.  And in even more cannot carry a blade that lock.  And even more cannot carry a  a fixed blade.

Answer (score 15):

This is sort of an obvious answer, but if you're worried about a knife slipping out of (or cutting through) a cheap sheath, then get a knife with a better sheath.

The traditional outdoors knife here in Finland is the [*puukko*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puukko), usually worn in a leather sheath that grips the handle by friction, with an internal wooden last that protects the leather from contact with the blade.  I've *never* heard of one of these knives cutting through the sheath, nor of slipping out accidentally, as long as the sheath is well made and fits the knife properly.

(The cheap plastic-sheathed [Mora knives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_knife) do tend to slip easily out of their sheaths.  As utility knives they're not too bad, but I'd *never* wear one of those things on my hip.)

Comment: While I love the Scandinavian and especially Finnish traditional knives (I own several), from my experience it can be difficult to access them with one hand. This is partly due to the good grip the sheath has on the knife, and partly because the sheath is often attached to the belt using just a single band/string at the top.

Comment: The last doesn't appear to be universal (I've got a similar knife which when I got it was the standard knife for the Finnish scouts). In that case the rather sturdy leather sandwiches the blade, and if you could cut through that you'd get to the rivets holding the sheath together.

Answer (score 12):

If your primary concern is "a knife I can quickly get out with just one hand" then you may want to look at better folding knives instead.  A modern folding knife should not be difficult to open with one hand.

If you need a fixed blade knife for other reasons I suggest you seek out (have made) a sheath that is leather-over-Kydex construction.  Kydex by itself can be rather brittle, especially in the cold.  Leather can be cut though, usually not by impact but by careless or forceful insertion/removal of the blade.  The leather-over-Kydex construction provides a particularly durable combination.

Be sure to get a sheath with positive retention as the knife coming free of the sheath is a more likely problem than the knife cutting through the sheath itself.

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using a Kydex or plastic sheath. You can also buy Kydex inserts for your leather/nylon etc. sheaths as well.

According to [Grant Lamontagne at the Multitool.org Forum:](http://forum.multitool.org/index.php?topic=22496.10;wap)

> The nice thing about kydex and other plastic type sheaths are that *they usually attach to the guard of the knife, meaning that any impact force isn't on the blade* through a soft material, it's on a hard shell and transferred through the hilt to the belt or other secure point, **meaning you are more likely to have it fall off your belt** than intrude on your innards.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Example of a Kydex sheath:

[image: Example of a kydex sheath]